# If $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to a bounded function $f(x)$, then $f_n(x)$ is bounded for all $n \in \Bbb{N^+}$ ？

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

If  $f_n(x)$   uniformly converges to a bounded function $f(x)$, then $f_n(x)$ is bounded for all $n \in \Bbb{N^+}$. Is this true?

I construct a counterexample as follows:

$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}1/x &n=1 \\ x+\frac{1}{n} &n\ge2
\end{cases}$, $\quad x \in(0,1)$

$f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $x$, whereas $f_1(x)$ is unbounded on $(0,1)$.

My questions:

(1) Is this example correct?

(2) Can it be claimed that there exists $N$ such that $f_n(x)$ is bounded for every $n \ge N$  if $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to a bounded function $f(x)$?

Comment: For $(2)$, use the definition of uniform convergence with $\varepsilon=1$, say.

Comment: THe first few terms could do all sorts of crazy stuff, but that doesn’t matter. So, (2) is the right statement (do you know how to prove it using the definition of uniform convergence though?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, here is my proof for (2):there exists $N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \le 1$ for all $n \ge N$, so $ |f_n(x)| \le |f(x)|+1 \le M+1$ for all $n \ge N$. (Suppose $|f(x)|≤M$)

Comment: "for all $n\geq N$ **and all $x\in X$**" (where $X$ is the common domain of all the functions).

Comment: $f_n$ is bounded **for all sufficiently large** $n$. Finitely many $f_i$ might be unbounded.